# Visual Basic 6.0 Shell command with spaces breaks

Tags: vb6

I am using the VB6 `Shell` command to run a program.

I am using the following syntax:

```
cmdline = "C:\Program Files\1\common\php\php.exe C:\Program Files\1\common\rpt\spc.php " & WorkOrderNo
taskId = Shell(cmdline, vbNormalFocus)
```

There seems to be an issue with the space between `Program Files` because the PHP command `spc.php` doesn't seem to execute. I can see a command window come up but it disappears too fast for me to read any errors. I can run the command application by hand just fine, just not using `Shell`.

How can I `Shell` using a path with spaces in it?

Comment: I don't believe spaces are the issue.  I was able to launch an app within `Program Files`.

Comment: You need to properly quote the paths in the command line, i.e., `cmdline = """C:\Program Files\1\common\php\php.exe"" ""C:\Program Files\1\common\rpt\spc.php"" " & WorkOrderNo`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, Thanks Justin, your suggestion seems to compile the report. Thank you. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly quote the paths in the command line, i.e.,

```
cmdline = """C:\Program Files\1\common\php\php.exe"" ""C:\Program Files\1\common\rpt\spc.php"" " & WorkOrderNo
```

Comment: How is this not obvious though?  The punctuation requirements are pretty widely known, and basically identical to what you must type at a command prompt.

Comment: I guess not a lot of (younger) people use the command prompt anymore.